# Как сделать в select отображение вместо выбранного значения свой текст?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="select-style">
    <select name="sort" id="sort">
        <option value="1" > ... </option>
        <option value="2"> ... </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

К примеру такой шаблон. По условию мне надо задать select свой вид, поэтому он обернут в div. Возможно ли как-то в данной ситуации изменить в select при загрузке страницы отображение вместо выбранного значения свой текст?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="select"> 
    <select>
        <option value="-1" selected>Бренд</option>    
        <option value="1">Pirelli</option>      
        <option value="2">Bridgestone</option>
        <option value="3">Nokian Hakka</option>
        <option value="4">Accelera</option>
        <option value="5">Continental</option>
        <option value="6">BFGoodrich</option>
        <option value="7">Dayton</option>                                   
    </select>
 </div>
```

Comment: Но в таком случае "Бренд" будет отображаться в списке выбора, а это недопустимо.

Comment: А все, понял...
<option value="-1" selected style="display:none;">Бренд</option>